# High MySQL Load 700% CPU usage

Tags: mysql, cpu

My mysql takes 700% of CPU while loading the website.
top command shows -

```
784% of CPU 
6.3% of MEM.
```

This is the output of lscpu command.

```
Architecture:          x86_64
CPU op-mode(s):        32-bit, 64-bit
Byte Order:            Little Endian
CPU(s):                8
On-line CPU(s) list:   0-7
Thread(s) per core:    2
Core(s) per socket:    4
Socket(s):             1
NUMA node(s):          1
Vendor ID:             GenuineIntel
CPU family:            6
Model:                 58
Model name:            Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E3-1230 V2 @ 3.30GHz
Stepping:              9
CPU MHz:               3499.804
CPU max MHz:           3700.0000
CPU min MHz:           1600.0000
BogoMIPS:              6584.91
Virtualization:        VT-x
L1d cache:             32K
L1i cache:             32K
L2 cache:              256K
L3 cache:              8192K
NUMA node0 CPU(s):     0-7
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15811411/high-cpu-utilization-in-java-application-why

Comment: Find out what queries are running (use `SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST;` or the slowlog), then let's discuss why they are chewing up so much CPU.

Answer (score 0):

This values are normal for 4 CPU cores with hyperthreading. Each core is loaded about 95% and the total amount is just a sum for loads for all 8 virtual cores. This certain load of 784% indeed is not appropriate and is an evidence of the poor DB performance. You need to optimize your queries/indexes to drop the load to the reasonable values.